# How to assign groovy function to a variable and call it?

Tags: groovy

I want to do something like this:

```
boolean flag = ...;
def foo(String x, String y) {
  // ...
}
def foo2(String x, String y) {
  // ...
}
def fun = flag ? foo : foo2;
fun("aaa", "bbb");
```

is something simillar possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [method pointers](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#method-pointer-operator):

```
def foo(String x, String y) {
   "FOO $x $y"
}
def foo2(String x, String y) {
   "FOO-TWOOO $x $y"
}

boolean flag = false
def fun = flag ? this.&foo : this.&foo2;
println fun("aaa", "bbb") // prints "FOO aaa bbb"

flag = true
fun = flag ? this.&foo : this.&foo2;
println fun("aaa", "bbb") // prints "FOO-TWOOO aaa bbb"
```

With Groovy 3, [you can do it the Java way too](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_lambda_expressions_and_the_method_reference_operator):

```
def fun = flag ? this::foo : this::foo2;
```